# Multiple stored procedure executions in one call

Tags: sql, web-applications, sybase

I have a stored procedure in Sybase that takes in a single date but I have to call it for a large time frame.  I am calling this from a web application so would be nice to submit one call to the db instead of multiple calls.  I am not able to modify the stored procedure, I have to use what is available.

```
 myspcall '1/1/2012'
```

What I would love to do is something like:

```
execute myspcall '1/1/2012'
UNION
execute myspcall '1/2/2012'
UNION
execute myspcall '1/3/2012'
etc...
```

I know that is invalid but then I would get one result set for the entire call.

Comment: Cant you duplicate the logic myspcall to use a range?

Comment: Unfortunately this is my only interface into the system.

Comment: can you do OPENROWSET in sybase?